# How would a 4 winged humanoid/centaur fly?

Tags: centaur, winged-humans, wings

Okay, i'm working on an OC for a fanfiction/RP i'm doing with a friend. She's a centaur like creature (body shape is closest to a cat, around 5'4 in Hight (if measuring her from her front paws to head) My goal with her features was to make her all terrain IE she is able to fly, swim and run quite well.
Now she's mostly based around sea birds like albatrosses and seagulls for her wing shape but because she's a centaur i gave her 4 wings, one set on her human back and one on her lower body both connect from the shoulder blades.
The problem here is i have NO IDEA how she would fly, I've been basing her flight off of Albatross flight but with 4 wings i'm not sure if she could properly soar the way I'm thinking.

*Few points ill mention, her feathers are completely water proof, she can start flying from the water by dolphin hopping, she is best suited for flying over the ocean but she can fly over land as she's closest to a seagull in wing shape.*

[the way she's turned in the air would be closest to this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJ3SN.png)

(yes she can also run like this. she's very long when like this but it makes her wings sit on the same plain. her upper wings are in-between her shoulders and her lower set are at her lower shoulders, she has a longer torso then imaged and her lower set are around 3ft total longer then her upper set. I think this answer's your question?)

[Here's her full character page if you want to look thru it. it should help a lot, just scroll down to the purple line and read from there.](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1B7FQCf83OR1CKhJA3pIoR_C2DH_0rP_tBwToW1jD4D8/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: What's the size of your creature? Are the 2 pairs of wings perpendicular to each other, like if you mixed a pegasus with an angel (pegasus flapping vertically, angel horizontally)?

Comment: Made like 5 edits that hopefully answer your questions. she would mostly flap horizontally but her wings shoulder and wrist act more like an arms and are ball joints.

Comment: It's been covered in much greater depth, but the easy one-word answer comes to mind: "poorly".

Answer (score 2):

**Cicada style**

[image: cicada]

[source](https://www.etsy.com/listing/763331933/one-beautiful-and-large-ghost-cicada?gpla=1&gao=1&&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=shopping_us_c-home_and_living-home_decor-taxidermy_and_curiosities-insects&utm_custom1=_k_CjwKCAjwx46TBhBhEiwArA_DjEunT8ndmklI-_nns1akO8l84mq3rk7uyU5rB6obrlJ-Rk8Eq4pUnxoCI30QAvD_BwE_k_&utm_content=go_12561588948_119850658695_506949566158_pla-306107311369_c__763331933_102461766&utm_custom2=12561588948&gclid=CjwKCAjwx46TBhBhEiwArA_DjEunT8ndmklI-_nns1akO8l84mq3rk7uyU5rB6obrlJ-Rk8Eq4pUnxoCI30QAvD_BwE)

Your cat centaur thing is hopefully more flexible than the usual horse human mixes.  SHe leans forward so her human torso is lined up with the cat torso and her 4 wings work like the wings of a cicada.

She is also cicada like in that she has 6 legs like a cicada.  I hope she also has eyes like a cicada but maybe that is asking too much.  Maybe her name could be "Cada"?

Comment: I already have her name picked and everything she's fully fleshed out already and i'm trying to keep her closest to a bird, but thank you for your response! :3

Answer (score 2):

## Realistically this would probably not work too well.

Since you're partially asking for some level of realism, here's the necessary addendum: Dragon-style bodies synergize very poorly with a large body size, especially if you're adding even more limbs to that mix. Your idea is good from an arthropod-like perspective where you have several limbs and can afford to specialize different limbs for different purposes, being a decent Jack of all trades, but flying is a big issue, because your wings need to be strong and your body must ideally be as light as possible. With that in mind, things like extra limbs make this troublesome because instead of having 2 wings with x muscle, you'll have 2 pairs which will most likely have more than x amount, but with added amount of weight from the second pair's skeletal structure. The large amount of limbs you have also means you're less streamlined, which here is twice as problematic since you want them to be both good fliers and good swimmers, and not being streamlined means your swimming speed should take a toll.

In an ideal world where we're still ignoring the square cube law' s annoying rules, but not completely, your centauroid character would probably benefit from a lack of upper body wings and a more wyvern-like lower body, with the wing limbs being the most powerful pair, sharing many traits with some azhdarchid pterosaurs. This would already mean they'd be lighter and more streamlined than if they had the dragon-style 6 limbed lower body with a 4 limbed upper body. The natural weight of the front part, lacking wings, would help balance out the lower body during flight, and they could still benefit from their wings, as the large size likely means they could achieve wings big enough for soaring. Something more or less

[image]

(funny enough this is pretty similar to the body shape I gave my own creature, a creature that was much more arthropod-like, but that also needed to be good at burrowing and wasn't a centaur. Taking a look at the fuzzy mole crickets might help you fleshing out your design much like it helped me in mine):

**that out of the way, something between a dragonfly and a puffin**

[image]

Puffins are a very cool type of bird for an important reason: they're good swimmers with a swimming style much like that of penguins, but they're also very good and speedy fliers! Their strategy is their wings, which are adapted for this hybrid locomotion lifestyle, and their habit of beating their wings up to 400 times per minute, or 20 times every 3 seconds (and also, their beaks are used by them as shovels to dig their burrows, making them decent diggers for a bird). Given what we want is something that needs to fly and swim well, this seems like one of the best ways other than modifying the tail and lower limbs for swimming.

*At this point I'll say it again however: your character will likely have a major part of its weight located on the lower body, so the pair of wings on the upper body would probably give it a lift it doesn't need, risking imbalancing their flight.*

As for however they'd flap their wings, ignoring weight issues, they'd probably be better off doing like dragonflies, which are agile aerial predators who use their 4 wings to their max potential, actually varying in the way they flap their 2 pairs of wings depending on whether they're traveling a long distance, hunting or hovering. Taking a look at their various flapping patters can help you to make the most of your character's 4 winged anatomy for maximum agility.

Comment: `ignoring the square cube law' s annoying rules` You're going in the naughty list.

Comment: You rase quite a few good points. i do still want her to have 4 wings but i was running with the assumption she would need a pair on her upper body, considering the idea's you've preposed though it would make more since for her to have 4 wings in a style closer to Valka's dragon in HTTYD, the 4 wings can also be used in tandem to make flight more like having one set. this would mean her "upper" set would be moved to her lower back or below her torso set and they would work in tandem more while still allowing more lift when needed. witch was my primary concern giving her 4 in the first place.

Comment: TLDR her wings are set in a way that allows them to work in tandem and cause less of a issue in that regard but from arial movement and take off she can use all 4 out of sink to generate more lift. it doesnt fix my wheight issue but im going to elect to ignore that. as for her aquatic movement, her wings all being on her torso helps that as she can fold them more like an actual birds wings up to her sides and swim more fluidly.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: @user95758 fair enough. I myself ignored the weight issues on my own version of this concept: a giant wyvern-like arthropod with a muscular tail and 6 limbs, none of which are remotely ideal for a large flying creature. Again I recommend looking at dragonfly flying patters, as they're the best example I know of a 4-winged flier that knows how to use them wings (not only can some species migrate across continents, they are the most successful predators in the world simply due to how well they fly in order to intercept their prey mid-air).

Comment: @TheSquare-CubeLaw lemme have me giant flying monsters dammit!

Comment: I think i figured out a slightly better design (that i was thinking of originaly lol) 
because of her torso langth i wanted her to have upper wings to support that half of her body so ive decided to go Harpy route and have them replace her arms with 3 fingers still outside of the wing at the wrist to allow her some semblance of hands.

Comment: as for the whole wyvern thing i looked over the entire answer again like twice and i miss read like 4 things so ive reevaluated. 
i kinda like the wyvern idea but because of how i want her to move in and out of water I've decided to make them 2 separate pairs of limbs still with the wings connected at the same shoulder kinda like this post → https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/152301/would-this-winged-human-angel-be-able-to-fly?rq=1

Comment: i did attempt to make her body more streamlined though, her entire body is very fluid with a more condesed lower ribcage to alow her more ferret/otter like movement. that long bodyed kind of swimming is kinda what i was going for though she can (and commonly does) act more like a normal centaur.

Thank you for your help! i was going to give myself a migrane trying to figure it out on my own.

Comment: Heres the full character sheet if you want to check it out! i linked it in the post but might as well link it here.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1B7FQCf83OR1CKhJA3pIoR_C2DH_0rP_tBwToW1jD4D8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @user95758 just a quick heads-up: depending on what you want going for them, they may not need both feathers and fur. Not only can feathers adapt into something very similar, they can offer great protection against water if properly oiled, meaning they could go for a dive and immediately leave almost completely dry. If their lungs are more mammalian than avian and lack an air sack system, a single set of large collapsible lungs and a circulatory system adapted for storing oxygen would also be good, both for deep diving and for high altitude flight.

Answer (score 0):

Given that pegasus flight is already kinda dubious, throwing in an extra set of wings on the other side of a very flexible joint sounds pretty awkward. Your weird 4-winged beastie probably would need to have abs you could bounce *boulders* off.

Here's the thing though... big flyers are generally soarers because flapping big wings hard and fast is really awkward and energy intensive. Just getting off the ground is a serious challenge. Consider that the forewings might just be used to generate a bit of extra *oomph* to simply clear the ground and give enough space for the main wings to operate properly. Once up a few meters they could just be tucked back (possibly with the arms tucked underneath them) to reduce the amount of aerodynamic drag they produce.

They could also be used to help perform sharp aerial turns (maybe to fight or evade, maybe to show off) or shed speed quickly (maybe to land on a small space). As such they could be rather smaller and neater than the main wings without necessarily being a useless burden or risking getting in the way.